# Check if django queryset have the same value in specific field

Tags: django, django-models

Is there any easier way to check if the query set have same value in specific field

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    is_finish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

```
y = Subject.objects.all()
```

how to know if y objects, each of them have is_finish == True without using for loop?
I just want to know that the queryset is giving me the same value for is_finish field.

Comment: why don't you just filter the queryset? i.e. `Subject.objects.filter(is_finish=True)`

Comment: because for example the user take course in university. he needs to finish all the subjects that he was assigned to graduate. So basically that is what i want to know so that i can put him in graduating list.

Comment: Very bad phrasing of the title. This phrasing implies the answer is how to filter records that have the same field relative to each other but you only want to filter by a pre-determined value... -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are several answers to your question:

Option 1:

```py
y = Subject.objects.all()
graduate = all(x.is_finish for x in y)
```

Option 2:

```py
y = Subject.objects.values_list('is_finish', flat=true)
graduate = all(y)
```

Option 3:

```py
y = Subject.objects.exclude(is_finish=True).exists()
graduate = not y
```

Option 4:

```py
y = Subject.objects.filter(is_finish=False).exists()
graduate = not y
```

Take the option matches better on your code.

Comment: or, possibly the fastest option: `Subject.objects.filter(is_finish=True).exists()`

Comment: @Ersain, thanks about `exists`. I wrote `any()` because I'm used to coding with c# and it uses `Any()` instead `exists()`